# Add String Arrays in ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` defined as:

```
ArrayList<String[]> params=new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

It contains parameters ("name", value) in String Arrays. I would like to insert elements in the `ArrayList`:

```
params.add({"param1", param1});
```

But when I try that I get an error.

What is the simplest way to add String Arrays in `ArrayList`. Do I have to declare a new array each time?

Comment: {"param1", param1} this is not a string array.

Comment: It looks like you really want a `Map`.

Comment: Just pointing that when you say `name/value` you might want to look at the [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A declaration is the only time you can just use braces, e.g.

```
String[] test = {"param1", param1};
```

In all other times, you must use `new String[]` also.

```
params.add(new String[] {"param1", param1});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a string with some special sequence. Add it in ArrayList and then split it when you need it. For example:

```
 ArrayList<String> str_list = new ArrayList<String>();
 String str = "name&&&value";
 // Add str to str_list
 str_list.add(str);
```

Then fetch it from arraylist and split it using following code:

```
 String str1 = str_list.get(index); 
 String[] values = str1.split("&&&");
```

values[0] will be name and values[1] will be value.

Answer (score -1):

You should read up on ArrayLists [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

But after initialization you can do this:

```
 params.add("String");
 params.add(aStringObject);
```

Your initialization is incorrect as well; If you want a ArrayList of Strings it should be:

```
 ArrayList<String> params = new ArrayList<String>();
```